# Python command to identify if a node is a databricks node or general node

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks

I have a requirement to develop a python application which can run on a normal machine like windows, linux or databricks. My requirement is to allow python application to dynamically identify where the script is actually running. If my python code is running on Windows, it should know that the code is running on windows. Like wise for Linux. I use Platform.system() to get the information. But databricks will also have a OS platform. How can it differenciate a databricks node from a normal Linux/Unix node? Apart from using dbutils or sparksession, will we be able to run a command and know that the node on which the command has run was indeed a databricks node?
I don't think that the databricks cli is installed on databricks cluster. so I haven't got any command to find out if the platform is Linux/Windows/Databricks.

Note:The application will be deployed on Windows/Linux/Databricks as a wheel file. So the requirement is that the application should identify, on which node the code is running. If it is running on windows/unix, it has to access the local file system and create some files on local file system. If it is running on databricks, it should access the mount point pointing to Azure ADLS and create/access files on/from ADLS.

Comment: Can you please provide additional information like what you have tried and any errors that you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I tried Platform.System() which specifies if it is a Windows or Linux machine. But a databricks node can also have a Linux OS right? So I am looking for a command by which the python application will figure out if the node is a normal Linux node or a Linux with Databricks. I tried to find out some commands to get this info. Unfortunately I did not find any.  Atleast if CLI was installed on Databricks, I would have used databricks --version or like command to find this info. If it fails then it is not a databricks node.

Comment: However, databricks cli cannot be installed on our environment. Also, if the cli is installed on windows or unix, python will start treating the non-databricks node also as a databricks node. So I am looking for something authentic command which is very native to databricks cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest check that you can do is to check presence of the `/databricks` folder on the driver node.  Additional checks could be done by checking for `/databricks/jars` director,, `/databricks/DBR_VERSION` file, etc.